# kendo multiselect typed text overlapped to selected items

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-multiselect

I implement kendomultiselect in my webapplication. there is a option in multiselect,

if we type a new item text in multiselect it will update the datasource and db. it's work fine. please see my code below.

```
function fnLoadDocumentTags() {
var newTagItem = "";

function onTagDataBound() {
    if ((newTagItem || this._prev) && newTagItem !== this._prev) {
        var ds = this.dataSource,
            datas = ds.data(),
            lastItem = datas[datas.length - 1];

        newTagItem = this._prev;

        if (/\(Add New\)$/i.test(lastItem.TagName)) {
            ds.remove(lastItem);
        }

        var newEntryFound = _.findWhere(datas, { TagName: newTagItem }) != null;

        if (newTagItem.length > 0 && !newEntryFound) {

            ds.add({
                TagName: newTagItem + " (Add New)", TagID: newTagItem
            });
            this.open();
        }
    }

}

function onTagSelect(e) {
    debugger;
    var dataItem = this.dataSource.view()[e.item.index()],
    datas = this.dataSource.data(),
    lastData = datas[datas.length - 1];

    if (parseInt(dataItem.TagID) > 0) {
        //////this.dataSource.remove(lastData);
    }
    else {
        if (newTagItem.length > 0) {
            var tagID = fnInsertDocumentTags(newTagItem);
            dataItem.TagName = dataItem.TagName.replace(" (Add New)", "");
            dataItem.TagID = tagID;
        }
    }

    ////$.each(datas, function (index, value) {
    ////    debugger;
    ////    if (datas[index].TagID == 0) {
    ////        var dummyItem = datas[index];
    ////        this.dataSource.remove(dummyItem);
    ////        return;
    ////    }
    ////});
}

function onTagClose(e) {
    fnTagsChangeSelect();
}

var data = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    batch: true,
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: urljsonGetDocumentTags,
            dataType: "json"
        },
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "TagID",
            fields: {
                TagID: {
                    type: "number"
                },
                TagName: { type: "string" }
            }
        }
    }
});

$("#Tags").kendoMultiSelect({
    animation: false,
    dataTextField: "TagName",
    dataValueField: "TagID",
    dataSource: data,
    dataBound: onTagDataBound,
    select: onTagSelect,
    close: onTagClose
});
}
```

But at the same time i face a issue like,when i type a text in multiselect the text overlapped to the selected items in multiselect. please see below image.

[image]

It would be nice any one have a suggestion...

Comment: Can you provide JSON string for `urljsonGetDocumentTags` and current CSS settings to reproduce the issue? Sounds like this issue related to `.k-multiselect-wrap` CSS selector.

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto your correct. I changed my css for this.

Comment: Is that your problem still continues? Just provide some missed things before so that this issue can be reproduced, even the problem source is CSS-related.

Comment: It's works fine now. thank you very much for your valuable replay..